# PUBLISH button is not appearing on the Context Menu

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, visual-studio-2019

I have been trying to deploy a web application is a .Net Framework

When I right-click on the project Solution, PUBLISH is nowhere to be found I tried Visual Studio 2017 and re-installed, checked and updated the workloads.

I check the checkbox: One-click publishing.
I gave up, I uninstalled it and installed Visual Studio 2019 same thing PUBLISH is not appearing anywhere.
I reset settings on import-export. I look everywhere on the NuGet package manager.
I am out of ideas.

Any hint would be appreciated. I will keep on digging. If ever I find a solution I will create a video because I spent several hours and my client is waiting for this application to be deployed on Godaddy Plesk. It is the first time I do this, I usually install scripts on LAMP Cpanel really easy.
This has been a nightmare for me, everywhere I see seems easy, right-click, click on Publish and create a profile or do Ftp or system files, azure.
But I can not get that blip Button PUBLISH.
Sorry, I am ranting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8rYDE.jpg)

Ok I do not know if all the re-install and all did something but @fatihyildizhan suggested to click on the web app logo below the solution and it did the trick!

Answer (score 0):

You don't right click the solution itself to publish, you right click the web layer of your project and you would see the publish button[image]